# Shuffle list / run through array items / divide method in two

Tags: android, arrays, shuffle

I'm writing a function where images are shown trough a shuffled list.

```
private int measurementCount = 0;

public int createShuffledList(){
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList< >();
    for (int i = 1; i <= MEASUEREMENTREPEATS; i++) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);

    Log.d("QD", "Shuffled index: " + indexes);

    int randomPrimeNumber = (int) indexes.get(measurementCount);

    Log.d("QD", "Value from index: " + randomPrimeNumber);

    primeindex = randomPrimeNumber;

    Log.d("QD", "Vale of primeindex index: " + primeindex);

    return primeindex;
}
```

What happens?

1. Shuffled list "indexes" is created
2. randomPrimenumber is the number of the item on position 0.
3. primeindex returns the number

An other method adds +1 to "measurementCount". Now the second item of shuffled list "indexes" should be returned (primeindex).

Calling the method again shuffles the "indexes" array again (not intended).

So I want to divide the method into two parts. The part of "shuffle index" should be called once (onCreate), the part of "get the next item" should be called multiple times (in a loop depending on measurementcount). So I'm writing in a wrong code what should happen:

Call once (oncreate):

```
public int createShuffledList(){
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList< >();
    for (int i = 1; i <= MEASUEREMENTREPEATS; i++) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);

    Log.d("QD", "Shuffled index: " + indexes);

    handoverIndex = indexes;
    return handoverIndex;
}
```

Call multiple times, measurementCount +1:

```
public int getNextShuffledListItem(){    
    int randomPrimeNumber = (int) handoverIndex.get(measurementCount);

    Log.d("QD", "Value from index: " + randomPrimeNumber);

    primeindex = randomPrimeNumber;

    Log.d("QD", "Vale of primeindex index: " + primeindex);

    return primeindex;
}
```

Is it possible to handover the shuffled array to the next method which runs through the items of the array?

Best and thanks in advance
tigercode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, your method (function) needs to return List of Integers

```
public List<Integer> createShuffledList(){
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList< >();
    for (int i = 1; i <= MEASUEREMENTREPEATS; i++) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);
    Log.d("QD", "Shuffled index: " + indexes);
    return indexes;
}
```

in your `getNextShuffledListItem()` method call specific element of list

```
indexes.get(yourIndex);
```

Watch out of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you can't call index beyond size of list.

=============UPDATE
Some class how to use your method

```
public class ExampleShuffledList {
    private static final int MEASUEREMENTREPEATS = 10;
    List<Integer> yourList;
    int measurementCount;

    public List<Integer> createShuffledList(){
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= MEASUEREMENTREPEATS; i++) {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(indexes);
        return indexes;
    }

    public void someMethodWhereYouWantToUseList(){
        yourList = createShuffledList();
        measurementCount = 0; //you declere it somehow
        Integer yourShuffledIndex = yourList.get(measurementCount); //just call get to get the index from list
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mij, but my getNextShufffledListItem() now doesn't find the "indexes" - do I have to declare them like an integer (or similar?)?

Comment: it is a little bit pointless. You can just call `indexes.get(measurementCount)` but your indexes must be a class variable, I updated answer check it out.